# When using splice to combine two arrays of objects, is the result always an array of pointers?

Tags: javascript

Is it always the case, meaning that it can be relied upon 100% of the time, that in the code below, no matter what is done to array `a` after array `b` is appended, such as sorting and adding/deleting/editing properties, apart from deleting the objects originally from array `b`, that `b` will always point to those objects? Even if `a` and `b` are passed from another function?

Perhaps, the more precise question is is `splice()` guaranteed to copy the references only, just like a pointer, and not copy the objects?

The fuller context is that I'm passing `a` and `b` to a function that sorts and manipulates the objects until finally using `array.filter()` to extract `b` and return it. Since `filter()` creates a new array, could less memory be used by not filtering/returning and using the original `b` references in the invoking function afterward? Or is that a bad practice that may lead to errors?

Thank you.

```js
"use strict";

let a = [ { "n" : "name_a[0]", "i" : 0 },
          { "n" : "name_a[1]", "i" : 1 },
          { "n" : "name_a[2]", "i" : 2 } ],
          
    b = [ { "n" : "name_b[0]", "i" : 0, "src" : "b" },
          { "n" : "name_b[1]", "i" : 1, "src" : "b" },
          { "n" : "name_b[2]", "i" : 2, "src" : "b" } ];
          
a.splice( a.length, 0, ...b );

a[3].i = 3;
a[4].i = 4;

console.log( b[0] );
console.log( b[1] );
console.log( b[2] );
```

Comment: Yes, before `let someArrayCopy = [...someArray]` became possible in ES6, a way to *`copy`* an array was to call `var someArrayCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call(someArray)`.

Comment: For some more ways on how to copy an array, look here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/